# How to call a function after Text has been entered in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to call a function after characters have been entered in my text input box. I tried bind but it calls it regardless if anything is entered. I am taking input from a hand scanner and displaying it in the textinput box. Then I will eventually send that including other info to a csv file.

main2.py

```
import kivy
import subprocess
import csv
import datetime
kivy.require('1.9.0')


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window





dt = datetime.date.today()
pafa = ''


#presentation = Builder.load_file('utest.kv')

class Barcode(TextInput):
    multiline = False

class PassFail(Label, Widget):
    pass

class UsbApp(App):



    def build(self):

        b= BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        t= Barcode(font_size = 50,

                    text="",

                    height=200,

                    background_color = (1,1,1,1)
                    )


        l=Label(text="Hey!",
                font_size=150
                )
        pf = PassFail(text='Pass/Fail',
                    font_size= 50,

                    background_color= (1,0,0,1),
                    color = (1,0,0,1),
                    bold=True
                    )

        t.bind(text = l.setter('text'))

        prompt=Label(text='Plug in device')

        b.add_widget(prompt)        
        b.add_widget(t)
        b.add_widget(pf)


        t.bind(text=Clock.schedule_once(self.run_test, 2))
        return b

    def detect(self):
        #detect when device is plugged in
        pass
        #device is detected change label

    #def on_text(self, barcode, clock):

        #self.barcode = Barcode().text

        #Clock.schedule_once(self.run_test, 2)

    def change_label(self):
        if self.prompt.text is 'Plug in device':
            self.prompt.text = 'Device detected'
        elif self.prompt.text == 'Device detected':
            self.prompt.text = 'Scan device'
        elif self.prompt.text == 'Scan device':
            self.prompt.text = 'Plug in device'

    def run_test(self, proc):

        #subprocess call to run app
        looptest = subprocess.call('sudo ./h2hlooptest -v', shell=True)

        #catch exit code then change label to Pass or fail
        if looptest == 0:
            pf = PassFail().text = 'Pass'

        else:
            pafa = PassFail().text = 'Fail'

        self.csv_write(pafa)

    def csv_write(self, pafa):

        with open("results.csv", "a") as csv_file:

            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            csvlist=[[dt, Barcode().text, pafa]]
            writer.writerows(csvlist)

if __name__=="__main__":
    UsbApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
t.bind(text=Clock.schedule_once(self.run_test, 2))
```

This doesn't bind the scheduling function to the text property, it *calls* the `schedule_once` function.

You need to pass a function to the bind method. In this case you could use a lambda function:

```
t.bind(text=lambda instance, value: Clock.schedule_once(self.run_test, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks but It still runs it with your new code without anything being put into the field. I would like it to run only after characters have done being entered in the field.

Comment: It's run when the text changes. It may additionally be run when the widget is first instantiated. If you want to make sure text has been entered, perform a check for this in the `self.run_test` function.

Comment: I performed a check "if Barcode().text is not None:" and still runs when widget is first instantiated.

Comment: @Wann I'm guessing `Barcode().text` isn't going to return the text of your already existing `t` instance, unless Kivy TextInputs are singletons or something weird. Additionally, I'd expect `.text` to be the empty string when no text has been entered, rather than `None`. You should try making `t` an attribute of `self` (that is, replace `t = ...` with `self.t = ...`), and try `if self.t.text != "":`

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, it works better. It actually runs when a character is typed. instead of on instantiation. I just now have to figure out how to get the entire sequence before running my function instead of each character. Thanks again!